# JS/JQuery : continue with the index of array of the form while generating new fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, forms

I have a form that is generated dynamically using PHP with a foreach loop.

The input fields of this form are inturn returning the data in a 3-D array which makes it easy to back-track where to submit these fields and how to store them. so here is is the form:

```
<?php

$i = 0;

foreach ($shop->fetch()->showResults() as $sr){
    $j = 0;
    if($i == 0){
        echo '<div id="ser'.$sr->id.'" location = "'.$sr->id.'" class="tab-pane fade active in">';
        $i++;
    } else{
        echo '<div id="ser'.$sr->id.'" location = "'.$sr->id.'" class="tab-pane fade">';
        $i++;
    }

    $ser = new Service(Input::get('cd'));
    $ser->fetchPriceInShop($sr->id, $ser->fetchData()->id);
    foreach ($ser->fetchData() as $price){
        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$price->duration.'" name="price['.$sr->id.']['.$j.'][duration]" placeholder="duration (in Minutes)">
              <input type="text" value="'.$price->price.'" name="price['.$sr->id.']['.$j.'][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
              <br>';
        $j++;
    }
    echo '
    <button style="float: right;" class="addPrice" type="button">+</button>
    </div>';
}

?>
```

so the resulting form is something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="10.00" name="price[1][0][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
<br><input type="text" value="20" name="price[1][1][duration]" placeholder="duration (in Minutes)">
<input type="text" value="20.00" name="price[1][1][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
<br><input type="text" value="30" name="price[1][2][duration]" placeholder="duration (in Minutes)">
<input type="text" value="30.00" name="price[1][2][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
<br>
```

now, I am trying to make this form flexible where I can add more fields to it and submit value using them. using the following js for that:

```
$(".addPrice").on("click", function(){
    var location = $(this).parent().attr('location');

    var element = '<input type="text" placeholder="duration (minutes)" name="prices['+location+'][index][duration]">';
    element += '<input type="text" placeholder="price (aud)" name="prices['+location+'][index][price]"><br>';
    $(this).parent().append(element);
});
```

I somehow managed to fetch the first index (location) and the last index are static, but I have no clue how can I find the second index of the array generated. Please help me figuring out the solution.

**PS: I am a noob at stack overflow so please don't be harsh. I am learning to use this platform.**

Comment: You shouldn't try to give each input field a unique name. Instead, give them all the same array names like `name="price[]"` and `name="duration[]"`. After that you can simply loop through those arrays in PHP to retrieve each value.

Comment: For DRYness, you can combine your two `i++` statements into a single statement if you write it after the if/else block.  That way the incrementing is guaranteed to occur regardless of if `$i=0`.

Comment: Perhaps reconfigure your multi-dim array structure to use indexes on the deepest elements.  In other words, declare as `price[$sr->id]['price'][]` then you don't have to bother with the incrementing of `$j`.  Then in your jquery you can just use: `name="prices['+location+'][price][]"` without  searching for the correct `index` to use.  This is basically the same principle that icecub has suggested.

Comment: I just realized a typo in the input name values -- `price` versus `prices`.  Just something to be fixed in everyone's codes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm recommending a re-structuring of your multi-dim array to avoid unnecessary counting / incrementing.

The form generating php code:

```
$i=0;
foreach($shop->fetch()->showResults() as $sr){
    echo "<div id=\"ser{$sr->id}\" location=\"{$sr->id}\" class=\"tab-pane fade",(!$i++?" active in":""),"\">";
        $ser=new Service(Input::get('cd'));
        $ser->fetchPriceInShop($sr->id, $ser->fetchData()->id);
        foreach($ser->fetchData() as $price){
            echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"{$price->duration}\" name=\"price[{$sr->id}][duration][]\" placeholder=\"duration (in Minutes)\">
              <input type=\"text\" value=\"{$price->price}\" name=\"price[{$sr->id}][price][]\" placeholder=\"Price ($ 100)\">
              <br>";
        }
        echo "<button style=\"float:right;\" class=\"addPrice\" type=\"button\">+</button>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

*note the `$i++` condition first checks if it is zero, then increments.  This maintains your intended use.  [Demo of this technique](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d26645dacb05a1a6496c52ad28390a49cab5c6f4)

The jquery code:

```
$(".addPrice").on("click", function(){
    var location = $(this).parent().attr('location');    
    var element = '<input type="text" placeholder="duration (minutes)" name="price['+location+'][duration][]">';
    element += '<input type="text" placeholder="price (aud)" name="price['+location+'][price][]"><br>';
    $(this).parent().append(element);
});
```

I might also like to recommend the use of `data-location` instead of `location` as an attribute name.

Comment: I thought of this as well but I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that there was a reason for the index, such as needing to maintain a sort order.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins How might this approach damage the sort order?  Have I overlooked something?  I think the only thing this will do is force the OP to recode the data handling after submission -- but not in a way that will be too troubling.

Comment: Generically speaking, if the array was being bound to a model or serialized, the data structure has changed. Generically speaking, using  xml as an example, the original might serialize as <data><option><duration>0</duration><price>1<price></option><option><duration>0</duration><price>1<price></option></data> but by changing the structure it might be. <data><duration><option>0</option><option>0</option></duration><price><option>0</option><option>0</option></price></data>. This might seem overly broad, but its not uncommon especially with the prevalence of JSON.

Comment: Consider the original structure: var price=[[],[]];
price[0][0]={duration:"value",price:"value"};
price[0][1]={duration:"value",price:"value"};
price[0][2]={duration:"value",price:"value"}
price[1][0]={duration:"value",price:"value"};
price[1][1]={duration:"value",price:"value"};
price[1][2]={duration:"value",price:"value"};
console.log(JSON.stringify(price));
[[{"duration":"value","price":"value"},{"duration":"value","price":"value"},{"duration":"value","price":"value"}],[{"duration":"value","price":"value"},{"duration":"value","price":"value"},{"duration":"value","price":"value"}]]

Comment: This is yours: var price=[{},{}];

price[0]["duration"]=["value","value","value"];
price[0]["price"]=["value","value","value"];
price[1]["duration"]=["value","value","value"];
price[1]["price"]=["value","value","value"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(price));

[{"duration":["value","value","value"],"price":["value","value","value"]},{"duration":["value","value","value"],"price":["value","value","value"]}]

Comment: comments are rather hard to read, perhaps a sandbox or pastebin would be better.

Comment: Yours is structure is more compact, but the original is ordered and can be bound as a key value pair list. It really depends on the needed use case though.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins Yes, I see your point and I agree.  Because I am a predominately PHP-guy I would choose to keep the js simple and let my php skills chew on the submitted array.  Personal preference.

Comment: Here's a pastebin. https://pastebin.com/EH6y12Ah Your solution does have benefits - more compact and easier to work with programmatically -  and is the way to got if there is no need to worry about changing the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to your price element and count the elements with that class.

```
 var idx = parent.find('.price').length;
```

```js
function parsePrice(el) {
  var parent = $(el).parent();
  var location = parent.attr("location");

  var idx = parent.find('.price').length;
  var element = '<input type="text" placeholder="duration (minutes)" name="price[' + location + '][' + idx + '][duration]">';
  element += '<input type="text" placeholder="price (aud)" name="price[' + location + ']['+idx+'][price]"><br>';
  
  $(element).insertBefore(el);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" location="1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
  <input type="text" value="10" name="price[1][0][duration]" placeholder="duration (in Minutes)">
  <input class="price" type="text" value="10.00" name="price[1][0][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
  <br><input type="text" value="20" name="price[1][1][duration]" placeholder="duration (in Minutes)">
  <input class="price" type="text" value="20.00" name="price[1][1][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
  <br><input type="text" value="30" name="price[1][2][duration]" placeholder="duration (in Minutes)">
  <input class="price" type="text" value="30.00" name="price[1][2][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="parsePrice(this);" value="go" />
</div>
```

Alternately you can group your elements inside of parent container, such as a `div` in your PHP loop:

```
 foreach ($ser->fetchData() as $price){
    echo '<div class="pricediv price-'.$sr->id.'"><input type="text" value="'.$price->duration.'" name="price['.$sr->id.']['.$j.'][duration]" placeholder="duration (in Minutes)">
          <input type="text" value="'.$price->price.'" name="price['.$sr->id.']['.$j.'][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
          </div>';
    $j++;
}
```

And then select a count of those elements:

```js
function parsePrice(el) {
  var parent = $(el).parent();
  var location = parent.attr("location");
  var idx = parent.find('div').length;
  var element = '<input type="text" placeholder="duration (minutes)" name="price[' + location + '][' + idx + '][duration]">';
  element += '<input type="text" placeholder="price (aud)" name="price[' + location + '][' + idx + '][price]"><br>';
  $(element).insertBefore(el);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" location="1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
  <div class="pricediv price-1"><input type="text" value="10" name="price[1][0][duration]" placeholder="duration (in Minutes)">
    <input class="price" type="text" value="10.00" name="price[1][0][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
  </div>
  <div class="pricediv price-2"><input type="text" value="20" name="price[1][1][duration]" placeholder="duration (in Minutes)">
    <input class="price" type="text" value="20.00" name="price[1][1][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
  </div>
  <div class="pricediv price-3"><input type="text" value="30" name="price[1][2][duration]" placeholder="duration (in Minutes)">
    <input class="price" type="text" value="30.00" name="price[1][2][price]" placeholder="Price ($ 100)">
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="parsePrice(this);" value="go" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Just found typo in OP's code, check inputs' name value `price` versus `prices`.  I've just changed mine to `price` (arbitrarily).

Comment: I'll follow your lead.  +1 for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use get elements by Tag name to find the index.

```
$(".addPrice").on("click", function(){
    var location = $(this).parent().attr('location');
    var index=$(this).parent().getElementsByTagName("input").length/2;
    var element = '<input type="text" placeholder="duration (minutes)" name="prices['+location+']['+index+'][duration]">';
    element += '<input type="text" placeholder="price (aud)" name="prices['+location+']['+index+'][price]"><br>';
    $(this).parent().append(element);
});
```

Comment: Although this is a solution, Please consider @icecub's suggestion of using the same name attribute for the group, that's the proper way to do it. Please accept my answer if you are satisfied.